# Why is my houseplant dying?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care

I have the plant in the picture. I have been watering it about every third day or so. Everything was going well, and new baby leaves started growing. But at some point in the last couple of weeks, it just started drying out. The new leaves are dead, and it seems to be spreading to the bigger leaves.

What can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm struggling to decide what your plant actually is, but regardless, it needs a bigger pot. As it stands, the ratio of topgrowth to size of pot is incorrect, and a plant is dependent on having sufficient root room to grow healthily. In regard to watering, ts always best to water when the surface of the soil feels a little dry, and then give it plenty of water, as well as never leaving any water afterwards in the outer pot - see below for clear watering instructions. It is also difficult for a rootbound plant to get enough water because the ratio of roots to soil is wrong - not enough unoccupied soil to hang onto any water for long enough.

Because I can't identify it, it's difficult to give proper care instructions, but find a pot with drainage holes that's one or two sizes bigger than the one its currently in, turn it out of its current pot and pot into the larger one, packing new potting soil beneath and around its rootball. Water in well, allowing excess water to drain away freely. Clip off dead leaves at the base, at soil level.

General care instructions for most houseplants are, water when the surface of the soil in the pot feels just dry to the touch - water thoroughly, and empty out any excess water in the outer pot or tray after 30 minutes, so the plant is not left sitting in water. Keep it out of sun, but ensure it has medium to bright daylight, in a position that isn't too draughty (such as by an open window or near a door), and keep away from heat sources such as radiators. If you have the label with the plant name, perhaps you could tell us what it says...

UPDATE

So its Monstera deliciosa; if you're not sure  whether to repot, turn it out of its current pot and see what the rootball's like - if its wrapped round with roots, find a bigger pot. Its usual to repot them annually when they're young.  The watering instructions given above are fine for this plant, but remember to empty out the outer pot afterwards - you could routinely mist it as well to increase humidity around it. https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/houseplants/swiss-cheese-plant/repotting-cheese-plants.htm

Comment: thanks for the very thorough reply! 
I went to the shop where I bought it from. Said said it is Monstera Deliciosa, and that I am watering it way too often. That generally it should be watered once a week. 
On the other hand, she said that the pot was okay for its size.

Comment: See updated answer...

Comment: Thanks @Bamboo!